# Как получить код символа который лежит в Char

Tags: c++

Используя студию всегда просто вычетал из этой переменной '0'
В мингв такое не работает вопрос почему?

Comment: Фрагмент неработающего кода, в котором не удается получить цифру вычитанием кода нуля из кода этой цифры в студию. Уверен, косяк в чем-то другом.

Comment: Если нужен сам код символа, то (int)Переменная
и получим её код. Если уж (Переменная - '0') совсем не пашет, то можно попробовать ((int)Переменная - (int)'0'). Но, как выше написали, косяк скорее всего в чём-то другом.

Comment: Приведение типов пашет, -'0' нет - почему?- незнаю но и на том спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В char'е лежит не символ, а как раз его код, который интерпретируется системой ввода-вывода как символ. Если нужно вывести это значения в терминале, то можно так

```
char a = 'a';
std::cout << (int) a << std::endl;
```

Или более культурно:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int> (a) << std::endl;
```

Comment: char может быть без знака со значениями, непредставимыми в int. Можно unsigned тип здесь использовать. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17882326/4279

Comment: стоит упомянуть что `c-'0'` используется чтобы получить десятичное значение символа с цифрой, а не его код. (`'0'-'0'==0`, но `(int)'0'` скорее всего не равен нулю, к примеру, если ascii используется, то `(int)'0'==0x30`)

Comment: это также подразумевает: что `UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX` (часто встречается)